# What would i need for this code to make turtles spawn slower, but not have to hold down the mouse to kill a turtle

Tags: netlogo

Im playing whack a mole, and here is my code thus far

```
globals [
  score
  three-sec-spawn
]

turtles-own [
  ttl]

extensions [bitmap]

To setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  import-drawing "whackamole.jpg"
  import-pcolors-rgb "whackamole.jpg"
  set-default-shape turtles "turtle"
  ask turtles [
    set size 7
    set color red
    set ttl 100] 
  reset-ticks
  ask patch 18 2 [set plabel 
  "DIRECTIONS : To kill a bug, click on it. If you misclick, the bug stays there."]
  ask patch 18 -1 [set plabel 
    "If there are 5 bugs on the screen, or if you dont kill it fast enough, you lose"]
  set score  0
  end

To play
  if ticks > 65000 - (difficulty * 10000) [user-message "GAMEOVER" stop]
  if (count turtles with [color = red]) = 10 [user-message "GAMEOVER" stop]
  ask turtles [
   set size 7
   set color red]

  ask patch 18 2 [set plabel ""]
  ask patch 18 -1 [set plabel ""]

  ask one-of patches with [pcolor = [42 13 9]] [sprout 1]
    ask turtles [
      set size 7
      set color red
      set ttl ttl - .5]

      wait .5

  if mouse-down? [
    ask turtles with [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor < 1.5] 
    [set score score + 1 
    die]
   reset-ticks
  ]
  tick
 end
```

because of the wait .5, turtles spawn too fast. But if i make the wait time any longer, id have to hold down the mouse button in order to "whack" the turtle

Comment: What's your question...?

Comment: i want the turtles to spawn slower, but at the same time not needing to hold down the mouse to kill a turtle

Comment: If your code is working, this isn't the place to be asking this questions. A better place would be the code review stack website: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes. Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: Alex: the code *isn't* yet working the way William wants it to, so it isn't suitable for codereview.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would not use the "wait." primitive at all, because it creates a gap of time where no actions (for example mouse clicks) can be tracked.
Instead I would use a time counter to delay the spawning and to create turtles on every x time units. Generally I would use the tick counter itself. For example, if you would like to spawn 1 turtle on every 100th tick:

if (ticks mod 100 = 0) [ ask one-of-patches with ... [sprout 1]]

In your example, the tick counter gets reset on mouse clicks. In that case you should define an additional time-counter for the spawning which does not get reset at anytime and gets increased by 1 on every timestep (analougous to the ticks but without resetting it back to 0 on mouse clicks):

if (*your-counter* mod 100 = 0) [ ask one-of-patches with ... [sprout 1]]

I hope this helps..?!?